# Accumulo on Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-emr, accumulo

According to Amazon [EMR documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hbase-s3.html), HBase can use Amazon S3 as data storage. I am using EMR to run apache accumulo database, is possible to store data in a S3 bucket?